# How to set the hoverlabel on the Y axis in PLotly in Python?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm new to Plotly. I tried my best but unable to set it. I want to hover both the labels simultaneous on the axes means at the end of the spike lines.

```
fig2 = go.Figure()

config = dict({'scrollZoom' : True})

# Add Close and Volume traces
fig2.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Close'], mode='none', fill='tozeroy', 
               fillcolor='green', hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor='rgba(23, 32, 42, 0.85)')))

fig2.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df['Date'], y=df['Volume'], marker_line_width=2, opacity=0.4, 
               hoverinfo='skip', hoverlabel=dict(bgcolor='rgba(23, 32, 42, 0.85)'), yaxis='y2'))

# Adding a line to show the previous Day Close price
fig2.add_hline(type='line', y=df['Close'].iloc[-2], line=dict(color='rgba(91, 99, 106, 0.2)', 
               dash='dot', width=0.8), annotation_text=round(df['Close'].iloc[-2], 3), 
               annotation_position='right', annotation=dict(bgcolor='#5b636a', 
               borderpad=2.5, font=dict(color='white', family='sans-serif')), layer='above')


# Adding buttons for periods
fig2.update_xaxes(
   title_text = 'Date',
   rangeslider_visible = False,
   rangeselector = dict(
        buttons = list([
           dict(count = 1, label = '1D', step = 'day', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 5, label = '5D', step = 'day', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 1, label = '1M', step = 'month', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 3, label = '3M', step = 'month', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 6, label = '6M', step = 'month', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 1, label = 'YTD', step = 'year', stepmode = 'todate'),
           dict(count = 1, label = '1Y', step = 'year', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(count = 2, label = '2Y', step = 'year', stepmode = 'backward'),
           dict(step = 'all')]),
           bgcolor='black',
           font=dict(color='#5DADE2')))

 fig2.update_yaxes(showgrid=False, spikecolor = 'black', spikedash ="solid", 
     spikethickness=0.5, spikemode = 'marker+across', spikesnap = 'hovered data', 
     tickprefix ='$')

 fig2.update_xaxes(spikecolor = 'black', spikedash ="solid", spikethickness=0.5, 
     spikemode = 'across+marker', spikesnap = 'cursor')

 # Update plot layout
 fig2.update_layout(
     autosize=True,
     template="plotly_white",
     showlegend=False,
     hovermode='x',
     xaxis_title=None,
     yaxis_title=None,
     hoverlabel=dict(namelength=0),
     barmode='relative',
     bargap=0.50,
     bargroupgap=0.0,
     grid=dict(ygap=1, xgap=1),

     yaxis=dict(
        side='right',
        showline=True,
        linecolor='rgb(189, 195, 199)',
        linewidth=2,
        fixedrange=True
     ),

     xaxis=dict(        
        showline=True,
        showticklabels=True,
        linecolor='rgb(189, 195, 199)',
        linewidth=2,
        dtick='M7'
     ),

    yaxis2=dict(
        overlaying='y',
        showticklabels=False
    )
 )

 xStart = ['2014-08-01', '2015-09-30', '2016-12-01', '2018-02-01', '2019-04-01', '2020-06-01', '2021-08-02']

 xStop = ['2015-03-03', '2016-04-30', '2017-06-30', '2018-08-30', '2019-11-04', '2020-12-31', '2022-03-02']

 for i in range(0, len(xStart)):
     fig2.add_vrect(x0=xStart[i], x1=xStop[i], fillcolor='#E5E8E8', opacity=0.38, layer='below', line=dict(color=None, width=0))

 # updating the xaxis hoverformat
 fig2.update_traces(xhoverformat='%d/%m/%Y')
```

This is what I'm getting. After wrting the above code. Kindly help me.
[What I'm Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPhq5.jpg)

I want to have like the below one. Also how can I make the volume traces a bit smaller on the the graph because its crosses the area, just like the below graph.
[What I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfo02.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For the display of spikes, the ability to display them on the axis is not implemented. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/). And to reduce the height of the volume, the height would be halved if the range of the volume axis is as follows. `range=[0,df['Volume'].max()*2]`

Comment: @Community I mentioned in the pic. Just kindly see the pic "What I Want". I need the hover label to be on the Y-axis and volume height to be bit shorter like the graph in the pic.

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for the information. I tried for the volume height , the code you provided but it's not working.

Comment: TRY this: `fig2.update_layout(..., yaxis2=dict(range=[0, df['Volume'].max()*2],        overlaying='y',showticklabels=False))`